# Does this condition characterise intervals, among subsets of the real line?

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-number-theory, convexity, computational-number-theory, power-series

For a real number, $c\in \left]0,1\right[$, consider the following property $\mathbf(\mathbf P_c\mathbf)$ of subsets $A$ of $\mathbb R$:

- $\mathbf(\mathbf P_c\mathbf)$ For every bounded set $B\subset \mathbb R$
  $$  B\subset A+cB\implies (1-c)B\subset A. $$
  This may be restated equivalently as:
- $\mathbf(\mathbf Q_c\mathbf)$ For every bounded sequence $(a_j)_{j\ge0} \subset A$ one has $(1-c)\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j c^j\in A$.

Indeed, if $A\subset \mathbb R$ satisfies $\mathbf(\mathbf P_c\mathbf)$, then take $B:=\bigl\{\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jc^j: (a_j)_{j\ge0}\subset A, \text{ bounded sequence}\bigr\}$, so $B\subset A+cB$, and by $\mathbf(\mathbf P_c\mathbf)$ we have  $(1-c)\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j c^j\in A$. Conversely, if $A$ satisfies  $\mathbf(\mathbf Q_c\mathbf)$, and $B$ is a bounded subset, say $B\subset [-M,M]$, such that $B\subset A+cB$, then, for every $b\in B$ we may form inductively a sequence $(b_j)_{j\ge0}\subset B$ and a sequence $(a_j)_{j\ge0}\subset A\cap [-2m,2m]$ so that $b_0=b$ and $b_n=a_n+cb_{n+1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. So $b=\sum_{j=0}^na_jc^j+b_{n+1}c^{n+1},$ and since $b_{n+1}c^{n+1}=o(1)$, we have $(1-c)b=(1-c)\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j c^j\in A$ by $\mathbf(\mathbf Q_c\mathbf)$, whence $(1-c)B\subset A$. In particular, we see that every real interval $A$ satisfies $\mathbf(\mathbf Q_c\mathbf)$.

The converse is also true, I think, which is no surprise: Every $A\subset \mathbb R$ verifying $\mathbf(\mathbf P_c\mathbf)$ (or $\mathbf(\mathbf Q_c\mathbf)$) is an interval. Yet I could not find a quick argument, and I'd like to see one, which is what I'm asking here. Both short existence proofs and constructive ones are welcome!

Note that if $A$ satisfies $\mathbf(\mathbf P_c\mathbf)$, so does every affine image of it, so if $A$ has more that one point, we can assume $\min A=0$ and $\max A=1 $. If $c=1/2$, property $\mathbf(\mathbf Q_c\mathbf)$ then says all binary expansions are in $A$, thus we can conclude that $A=[0,1]$, and  the same observation is sufficient to treat the case of $1/2\le c\le 1$. For $0<c<1/2$, these points would only produce a Cantor set, but we can plug them again as sequences in $\mathbf(\mathbf Q_c\mathbf)$, so actually we have
$(1-c)^2\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_{ij} c^{i+j} \in A$ for all bounded double sequences $(a_{ij})_{(ij)\in\mathbb N^2}\subset A$, and more generally, iterating,

$$(1-c)^m\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{\substack{j\in\mathbb N^m\\ |j|=m}} a_{j_1,\dots,j_m}\right) c^m\in A $$
for every $m\in\mathbb N$ and every bounded family $(a_j)_{j\in \mathbb N^m}\subset A$. In particular, also

$$(1-c)^m\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{m+k-1}k a_k c^k\in A $$
for every bounded sequence $(a_k)_{k\in \mathbb N}$ and integers $0\le n_k\le \binom{m+k-1}k$. These seem sufficient to conclude, but is it necessary to follow this path?

Comment: Let $A$ contain $0$ and $1$. Let $I=(a,b)$ be the longest open subinterval of $[0,1]$ disjoint with $A$ (if it exists). Take $a',b'\in A$ very close to $a,b$. Then $(1-c)a'+cb'\in A\cap I$ - a contradiction. Thus $A$ is dense in $[0,1]$. The rest is obvious: to get $x\in[0,1]$ as a sum of the series just overshoot $x-c^{j+1}$ by a tiny little bit when adjusting the $j$'th partial sum by the choice of $a_j$.

Comment: Yes, I had something like that in mind, but writing it, it went out a bit ugly

Comment: *"but writing it, it went out a bit ugly"* Where? What I wrote is a complete proof, isn't it?

Comment: Will you write it as an answer? So I can accept it and it doesn't appear unanswered :)

Comment: Notice the conspicuous typographical difference between $c\in]0,1]$ and $c\in\left]0,1\right].$ Clearly the former is incorrect. I fixed it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461646/does-this-condition-characterise-intervals-among-subsets-of-the-real-line#comment1197567_461646), while `\left]` and `\right[` fix the spacing, they can have unwanted sizing effects—consider, for example, $c \in \left]0^2, 1^2\right[$ `c \in \left]0^2, 1^2\right[`.  The spacing can be achieved without the sizing side effect using `\mathopen` and `\mathclose`, e.g., $c \in \mathopen]0^2, 1^2\mathclose[$ `c \in \mathopen]0^2, 1^2\mathclose[`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(not to leave this unanswered)* As observed in [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461646/does-this-condition-characterise-intervals-among-subsets-of-the-real-line#comment1197437_461646), the answer is quick as we know that $(1-c)^m\sum_{k\ge0} n_k c^k\in A$ for all $m\in\mathbb N$ and all choices of integer coefficients  $0\le n_k\le \binom{m+k-1}k$; in fact a single $m$ such that $(m+1)c\ge1$ is sufficient.
To simplify the description, we may see any such series $(1-c)^m\sum_{k\ge0} n_k c^k$ equivalently as a sum $\sum_{j\in J}w_j$ of a sub-family of a sequence $(w_j)_{j\in\mathbb N}$, where the $w_j$'s are just the $(1-c)^mc^k$, each repeated $\binom{m+k-1}k$ times, in decreasing order. The condition $(m+1)c\ge1$ ensures that $w_j \le \sum_{i>j} w_i$ for all $j\ge0$.

A general basic principle (classic stuff I think) to refer to:

> *Let $(w_j)_{j\in\mathbb N}$ be a decreasing sequence of positive weights summing to $\sum_{j=0}^\infty w_j=1$. Denote $r_j:=\sum_{i>j} w_i$,
> and  $S:=\bigl\{\sum_{j\in J}w_j: J\subset \mathbb N\bigr\}$, the set of
> all sums of sub-families of the weights. Then $S=[0,1]$ if and only if
> $w_j\le r_j$ for all $j\ge0$.*

Sketch: For every $x\in[0,1]$ we can form a binary sequence $(\epsilon_j)_{j\in\mathbb N}\in \{0,1\}^\mathbb N$  defining inductively $\epsilon_j=1$ iff $\bigl(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\epsilon_iw_i\bigr)+w_j\le x$. By construction, $\epsilon_j=1$ eventually, only if $e_j=1$ for all $j\ge0$, and this implies that  $x= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\epsilon_iw_i$. On the other hand, if for some $j$ one has $r_j<w_j$, then $S\cap\mathopen]r_j,w_j\mathclose]=\emptyset $.